# Azure Functions IP addresses out of range

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, firewall

I have a Azure Function, which makes calculations and stores and reads data from my own Cosmos DB and one external database via REST API.

From Azure Portal, I can see the "outboundIpAddresses" and "possibleOutboundIpAddresses" (subscriptions > {your subscription} > providers > Microsoft.Web > sites). Totally 12 IP addresses. When I run the function locally (VS Code), everything goes smoothly. However, when I deploy that function, I get the following error:

```
Result: Failure Exception: CosmosHttpResponseError: (Forbidden) Request originated from client IP <IP-address> through public internet. This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings
```

This itself is self-explanatory, but the problem is that the IP-address mentioned in the error message does not belong neither "outboundIpAddresses" or "possibleOutboundIpAddresses". And almost every time the function gets triggered, the client IP in the error message changes.

Do you have any ideas why this happens and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your function app in Consumption plan? If yes, when a function app that runs on the Consumption plan is scaled, a new range of outbound IP addresses may be assigned. When running on the Consumption plan, you may need to whitelist the entire [data center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519).

On further note, if you are into app service plan, you have the option of assigning [dedicated IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#dedicated-ip-addresses) .